# Sort through a Pandas dataframe and save unique entries

Tags: python, pandas, loops, data-science

I'm trying to figure out how to sort through rows in a spreadsheet read with pandas and save values to variables.

Here is my code so far:

```html
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
 
df = pd.read_excel('data_file.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet 1')


for line in df:
    if line.startswith(line):
```

The data is formatted the following way:

Column 1 has runner numbers, column 2 has 100 meter sprint times, Column 3 has 400 meter sprint times.

Here's an example of the data:

```html
Runner  100m   400m
  1     43.7   93.5
  1     37.5   87.6
  1     39.2   82.5
  2     28.9   67.9
  2     26.2   69.9
  2     33.3   60.25
  2     34.2   60.65
  3     19.9   45.5
  3     19.8   44.0
  4     18.7   50.0
  4     19.0   52.4
```

How could I store the contents of all the rows starting with 1 in a unique variable, all the rows starting with 2 in another variable, 3, etc.? I know this has to involve a loop of some sort but I'm not sure about how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to avoid trying to programmatically set unique variables.  This problem is probably best approached using a dictionary data structure to store the contents of the rows, with keys for each "Runner" ID (but runners would need to be unique).

You can quickly iterate through the data for each runner using pandas groupby.  In the loop, the i represents the "Runner" ID and tdf is the dataframe of just data for that runner.  This would store a numpy array of the data for each runner in dict d.

```
d = {}
for i, tdf in df.groupby('Runner'):
    d[i] = tdf[['100m', '400m']].values
```

EDIT:
If you really want to iterate line by line you can use df.iterrows() method.

```
d = {}
for i, x in df.iterrows():
    runner = x['Runner']
    data = x[['100m', '400m']].tolist()
    d[runner] = d.get(runner, []).append(data)
```